# Validate LargeBinary field using Pydantic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

Lately I've been studying design patterns, SOLID principles and stuff like that and I started working on a small project to apply these concepts. I collect postage stamps and the project is to upload stamps info. My model is simple:

```
class Stamp(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stamps"

    id: uuid4 = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title: str = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    year: int = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    post_office: str = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    description: str = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    photo: str = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
```

I'm using repository pattern to isolate DAL from the application domain:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from uuid import uuid4

from .models import Stamp

class StampRepository:
    @staticmethod
    def find_all(db: Session) -> list[Stamp]:
        """Retrieve all data from database"""
        return db.query(Stamp).all()

    @staticmethod
    def save(db: Session, stamp: Stamp) -> Stamp:
        """Add and update stamps"""
        if stamp.id:
            db.merge(stamp)
        else:
            db.add(stamp)
        db.commit()
        return stamp

    @staticmethod
    def find_by_id(db: Session, id: uuid4) -> Stamp:
        """Retrieve stamp data filtering by id"""
        return db.query(Stamp).filter(Stamp.id == id).first()

    # TODO: write another search method - name based instead of id based
    @staticmethod
    def exists_by_id(db: Session, id: uuid4) -> bool:
        """Check for stamp"""
        return db.query(Stamp).filter(Stamp.id == id).first() is not None

    @staticmethod
    def delete_by_id(db: Session, id: uuid4) -> None:
        """Delete stamp based on its id"""
        stamp = db.query(Stamp).filter(Stamp.id == id).first()

        if stamp:
            db.delete(stamp)
            db.commit()
```

And I'm using Pydantic to validate my models:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import LargeBinary
from uuid import uuid4

class StampBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    year: int
    post_office: str
    description: str
    photo: LargeBinary

class StampRequest(StampBase):
    ...

class StampResponse(StampBase):
    id: uuid4

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed=True
        orm_mode = True
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
raise PydanticSchemaGenerationError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for 
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.LargeBinary'>. Set `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the model_config 
to ignore this error or implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on your type to fully support it.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Shouldn't the custom model configuration reside inside the `StampBase` class?
Btw, starting from `v2.0` `Config` class is [deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/model_config/).